# A link gets activated without being clicked in Outlook email

Tags: node.js, outlook, gmail, nodemailer

I send an email using `nodemailer` and `node.js` for sign-up process to make sure a user put in a valid email address.
My whole sign-up process is like the following.

1. A user submits their email address with other information such as username and password.
2. The user gets an email to verify their email address.
3. The user clicks on the link in the email to complete their sign-up process.

I believe this process is very common.

When a user submits their sign-up form with **gmail** account, they can complete their sign-up process by **clicking the link** in the email, which is absolutely what I want.

However, when a user submits their sign-up form with **outlook** account, they complete their sign-up process by ONLY **clicking the email** not the link.

In other words, the link in the email gets activated without being clicked in Outlook.

I'd like to make sure that the link in the email gets activated only when it is clicked in Outlook.

Comment: I think that might be some outlook way for checking links in email for possible exploits. Gmail does the same by providing link through proxy server. Show us the logs for request, specifically `user-agent`. Also it is a nice idea to have a confirmation button that posts on link for final validation. :)

Comment: I thought I was going crazy trying to figure out why my email link was getting 'clicked twice'. I didn't realize opening the email submitted the link! So much wasted time... :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a `user-agent` header when this Outlook's request is being issued:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534+ (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) BingPreview/1.0b

So you may try to check whether it contains the "BingPreview" string (this is what I've done with a simple String.contains(..)), or maybe a more proper solution would be to parse the whole `user-agent` string into components and check the proper one.

By the way here is some information on this crawling behavior: https://blogs.bing.com/webmaster/2012/10/26/page-snapshots-in-bing-windows-8-app-to-bring-new-crawl-traffic-to-sites/

Though the most proper way of course would be not to send the direct confirmation link in email, but instead send a link to a confirmation page with a button, which in its turn calls the confirmation link.